# Make an image after flatted fully connected layer in CNN

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using this reference project/paper https://feedforward.github.io/blog/depthmap-prediction-from-a-single/ for predicting the depth estimation from 2D images. I cannot understand how the coarse depth image (Coarse7) is formed after the fully connected layer.

I am using an color input image of size (576,172)

````
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.applications import vgg16
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, InputLayer,UpSampling2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
import cv2

model=Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(96,(11,11),strides=(4,4),input_shape=new_arr.shape,padding='same'))
# model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256,(5,5),padding='same'))
# model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(384,(3,3),padding='same'))
# model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation("relu"))
# model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(384,(3,3),padding='same'))
# model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation("relu"))
# model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Dense(256))
# model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096))
# model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))
# model.add(Conv2D(128, 5, padding='same',activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))

model.summary()
This the model summary
```Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_94 (Conv2D)           (None, 43, 144, 96)       34944     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_137 (Activation)  (None, 43, 144, 96)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_79 (MaxPooling (None, 21, 72, 96)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_95 (Conv2D)           (None, 21, 72, 256)       614656    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_138 (Activation)  (None, 21, 72, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_80 (MaxPooling (None, 10, 36, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_96 (Conv2D)           (None, 10, 36, 384)       885120    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_139 (Activation)  (None, 10, 36, 384)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_97 (Conv2D)           (None, 10, 36, 384)       1327488   
_________________________________________________________________
activation_140 (Activation)  (None, 10, 36, 384)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_44 (Dense)             (None, 10, 36, 256)       98560     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_141 (Activation)  (None, 10, 36, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_81 (MaxPooling (None, 5, 18, 256)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_44 (Dropout)         (None, 5, 18, 256)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_14 (Flatten)         (None, 23040)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_45 (Dense)             (None, 4096)              94375936  
_________________________________________________________________
activation_142 (Activation)  (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_45 (Dropout)         (None, 4096)              0         
=================================================================
Total params: 97,336,704
Trainable params: 97,336,704
Non-trainable params: 0
````

Answer (score 0):

After you have an flattend image or a dense layer you can reshape it to an image size with keras.layers.Reshape.
Than just upsample it to your output size.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Reshape

I hope that helped